# Submit IPhone app on the app store, then decide to submit an IPad app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I have never submitted an app to the appstore, but I will in the near future.

So far I am becoming quite comfortable with designing for the IPhone but not the IPad.

I understand that by putting a universal **PAID** app on the appstore that the customer would only have to pay once to have access to both the iPhone and Ipad versions.

What if you submit an IPhone app for $0.99. then later decide you also want an IPad App version for $0.99.

Would the consumer have to purchase both?

Or is there a way to tell Apple that "this is the IPad app" of this IPhone version, and so the consumer would only have to pay a one time fee (if he has already purchased the Iphone app = free download for Ipad App).

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just one app at one price, you can submit the app again (in a subsequent version) as a Universal app that runs natively both on iPhone and iPad. This kind of thing happens quite often, as developers expand their horizons...

If you submit an iPhone only app and an iPad only app they will be two separate apps with two different names and two separate prices. People do that - the New York Times app works that way, I believe - but it isn't as common. For one thing, it's confusing, because the iPhone version will run on the iPad, but as an iPhone app, so the user may not realize this is the wrong app (and it will probably look kind of crappy).

GoodReader is another well-known example where the iPhone version and the iPad version are two separate apps: see http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html

Comment: thankyou, the "you can submit the app again (in a subsequent version)" was what I needed, also cheers for the extra info :D.